# Android : Sting returning with null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I am having a problem with my notepad code. I have made a notepad with save button which firstly displays the string that we entered on click of button. For that purpose I made a class called "LinedEditText.java" but when I run my code I am getting exception called "Null Pointer exception". Here is my code, please let me know what should I do ? Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class NotePadActivity extends Activity {

        LinedEditText noteTxt;


        Button remind, save, cancel;
            String str="";


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.notepad);

noteTxt=(LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.noteTxt);


            save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
            cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

            save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String str = (noteTxt.getText()).toString();
                    Log.i("Notepad String:", "" + str);
                }
            });
```

LinedEditText.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        // mPaint.setColor(R.color.edit_note_line); // SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // int count = getLineCount();

        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();// for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);// first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();// next line
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

notepad.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/320x480x2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lin" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noteTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="Note"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reminderBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="#78C7C7"
            android:text="Set Reminder" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.ashish.ashish.LinedEditText
        android:id="@+id/noteTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:height="200dp" >
    </com.ashish.ashish.LinedEditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/noteTxt"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#78C7C7"
            android:text="Save" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#78C7C7"
            android:text="Cancel" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String str = noteTxt.getText().toString();// GETTING EXCEPTION HERE
                Log.i("Notepad String:", "" + str);
            }
        });
```

EXCEPTION is;

```
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com..NotePadActivity$2.onClick(NotePadActivity.java:49)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-28 11:26:57.494: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you declaring noteTxt in the MainActivity?, and getting a reference to it?

Comment: please add your hole Main Activity code here.... i think you forgot to declare noteTxt in MainActivity..

Comment: yes I have already declared it like this, LineEditText noteTxt=(LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.noteTxt);

Comment: Post your NotePadActivity.

Comment: Read the stack trace. The exception happens at line 49 in NotePadActivity.java. Something is null at this line. What is this line of code?

Comment: See I have posted the MainActivity.java

Comment: show us where is your line 49 also not only just post your code

Comment: May be issue with package name, make sure that passed package name to`LinedEditText` in xml it should be correct.

Comment: Could you check if value of noteTxt after the line `noteTxt=(LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.noteTxt);` is null or not?

Comment: Can you share LinedEditText.java` package name?

Comment: package name : com.ashish.ashish;

Comment: It seem you edited and changed your package name, now do check, hope it works

Comment: No it doesn't work. @Amulya Khare: how to check that ?

Comment: @RobinHood If the package names didn't match, there would have been an `InflateException`.

Comment: @AshishPatil : hello just try my trick because i have same problem as you and solved by change in declaration..... agar sahi lage to try karo ...

Comment: After the line just check `if(noteTxt == null) Log.i('Value is null')`. You can also use the debugger.

Comment: @BlackTiger : kaunsi trick ? Kindly edit my code and let me know

Comment: Post complete notepad xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all three default constructor for LinedEditText class. It may solve your problem.

```
public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

}

public LinedEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);

}
```

Comment: @Brijesh Patel : Done this. How to declare that view in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: My declarations in MianActivity.java are correct ? Because now I am getting exception 09-28 12:09:05.823: E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ashish.ashish/com.ashish.ashish.NotePadActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

Comment: Everything else should remain the same. This is basically constructor overloading. You can either copy the initialization code (the code after super call) to all three constructors, or pass the call to one constructor using `this(context, null, 0)` and `this(context, attrs, 0)` in two of the constructors. In this case, the initialization code will go inside `public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`.

Comment: edit your question with layout xml and from your notepadActivty (ctrl+l enter 49) and that line only post me here.

Comment: noteTxt=(LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.noteTxt);//line 49          layout edited

Comment: hi post another answer check it out . it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    you already defined id noteTxt for TextView here.

      <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="Note"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp" >
            </TextView>

     So change id for LinedEditText view..

     <com.kalnirnay.kalnirnay.LinedEditText
            android:id="@+id/noteEdt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:height="200dp" >
        </com.kalnirnay.kalnirnay.LinedEditText>
same in code..
   LinedEditText noteEdt;
                  noteEdt=(LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.noteEdt);
```

Comment: WORKED !!!!!! thanks a lot man !!!!! i was working like an idiot on the same from last 4 hrs !!! thanks :D